# How to make shapes clickeable in a .svg file

Tags: hyperlink, svg

This is not a question about handling svg tags inline html body, it is about file.svg content to use like
     `<img src="file.svg" type="image/svg+xml">`
In Adobe Illustrator I created some graphic design and then include some  rectangle areas I need add hyperlinks to them.
Export for svg creates the file but it lacks the hyperlinks defined in each rectangle attribute.
I am asking how to do it manually.
Using a code editor I see AI adds a `xlink` reference but it does not use it to build hyperlinks.
I've read it is only possible using the expanded svg script inside a html body.
I tested that adding xlinks to those rectangles, and links appeared as expected for each of them.
This not the case when I have to use `<img src="file.svg" type="image/svg+xml">`
I need to add them inside (I also checked that way, just in case, unsuccessfully)

Here's a simplified version of my `file.svg`
I want to add an hyperlink to the last `rect`

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 344.92 164">
<defs>
<style>
  .cls-1 {
    fill: url(#linear-gradient);
  }

  .cls-2 {
    fill: #108daa;
  }
</style>
  <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" y1="82" x2="344.92" y2="82" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#00a651"/>
  <stop offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
</defs>
  <rect class="cls-1" width="344.92" height="164"/>
  <rect class="cls-2" x="89" y="50.5" width="174.5" height="67"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: <img> elements are not interactive so this is not possible. You'd have to make the SVG inline or use another element such as <object> or <iframe>

Answer (score 1):

You can create links in your SVG in a similar way to HTML. You use an `<a>` element.

Then you need to embed your SVG using one of the methods Robert suggested.

```css
svg a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 344.92 164">
<defs>
<style>
  .cls-1 {
    fill: url(#linear-gradient);
  }

  .cls-2 {
    fill: #108daa;
  }
</style>
  <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" y1="82" x2="344.92" y2="82" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#00a651"/>
  <stop offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
</defs>
  <rect class="cls-1" width="344.92" height="164"/>
  <a xlink:href="/"><rect class="cls-2" x="89" y="50.5" width="174.5" height="67"/></a>
</svg>
```

Comment: Original SVG has a lot of paths, too long to input inline. For me the correct answer is to use `<object>`or `<embed>` without having to add `xlink`. And in some cases `pointer-events: visible;`is also needed